# React-Native Auto Collapsing View on tap

Tags: javascript, react-native, animation, react-state

[image]

I am trying to replicate this picture by having a collapsing view that when pressed it expands while all the content is not visible. Is this possible to do in react-native without a library, I tried adjusting the height of the view but it does not hide the content it just decreases the container size.How do I hide an show the content and add a small animation to reveal the contents.

Please can someone assist me with this I'm not sure how to do it

This is the view Code

```
<View style={{ marginLeft: 30}}>
  <Text style={styles.title}>
    Traveller ✈️ Book Lover  Obsessed with tacos  We love all animals  and
    donate a percentage of sales to marine life 
  </Text>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used for this and it was really handy. [react-native-collapsible](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-collapsible)